# Find $HOME or Windows equivalent with FreePascal

Tags: configuration-files, directory, detect, freepascal

My purpose is to deploy user configuration files under:

- $HOME/.appname for Unix/Linux.
- \Documents and Settings\(user)\Application Data\AppName for Windows.

What are the API's or group of functions that I can use, with the appropriate {$IFDEF}'s, so I can deploy my config files on the appropriate places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the correct function:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getappconfigdir.html

result:=getappconfigdir(false)

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely end up using the [`GetEnvironmentVariable` function](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getenvironmentvariable.html). Under Unix-like OSs, you will use the `HOME` environment variable. Under Windows, you'll use the `APPDATA` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks mate. It's good to know that it works fine, and the same way, under both Windows and *NIX systems.

Comment: `{$I %APPDATA%}` can be used as shorthand for `GetEnvironmentVariable('APPDATA')`